# C++ Cyclic pointer injection in constructor

Tags: c++, dependency-injection

I've read a lot of circular dependecies topics, but I couldn't find the one solving my problem. I have two classes containing pointers to each other:

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
    A(B* _b, int _c): b(_b), c(_c) {}
    B* b;
    int c;
};

class B
{
public:
    B(A* _a, int _d): a(_a), d(_d) {}
    A* a;
    int d;
};
```

The problem is that in the following code:

```
class C
{ 
public:
    A* a_ptr;
    B* b_ptr;
    C() 
    {
        a_ptr = new A(b_ptr, 3);
        b_ptr = new B(a_ptr, 2);
        qDebug() << a_ptr->c;
        qDebug() << b_ptr->d;
        qDebug() << a_ptr->b->d;
        qDebug() << b_ptr->a->c;
    }
}
```

last two lines are crashing application. I understand the problem and the reason of crashes. I could write setters for members and invoke them AFTER creating objects, so the pointers will be valid. However, I want the objects to be complete after invoking contructors, without invoking any other methods.

So... I was wondering if there is any way to inject (cyclic) pointers in constructors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make one contructor complete the initialization of the other object:

```
B(A* a_ptr) : a(a_ptr)
{
    if(a)
        a->b = this;
}
```

And same for `A()`. Thus, you can create them like the following:

```
a_ptr = new A(b_ptr, 3); // b_ptr was initialized to 0
b_ptr = new B(a_ptr, 2); // b_ptr->a = a_ptr
                         // b_ptr->a->b = b_ptr (ie, a_ptr->b = b_ptr)
```

**Edit**: As stated in the comment, this is not scalable if you have a lot of classes. However, in the general case you will have to initialize cyclic dependencies *outside* of constructors, and secondly you shouldn't have a a lot of classes that cyclicly depends on each other (if it is the case, maybe you can rearrange your code...).

Comment: What if you add in several more classes that all depend on each other? This approach will work in the simple case, but it unmanageable in the long run. Simple example, what if some other developer makes B first then A? That said, solves OP.

Comment: I agree, this is not scalable. However, there are no solutions as the OP wants, this is the only way to create objects only using constructors, without initialization code after the creation...

Comment: That's technically not true, B is doing a second initialization on A, by putting a->b_ptr = this. i.e. the state of A is not complete via its own constructor. It requires a second initialisation, which you've just hidden in B.

Comment: Yes, but the state of `A` cannot be complete before `B` is created... And all is done in constructors (even if not the class own constructor).